# Prolog Query Exercise - Beginner

Tags: prolog

I'm a begginer at Prolog and I need some help with this exercise, this is the knowledge base provided:

```
album(‘R. Stevie Moore’, ‘Manuscription’).   
album(‘Lane Steinberg’, ‘Manuscription’).  
album(‘R. Stevie Moore’, ‘The Yung & Moore Show’).  
album(‘Yukio Yung’, ‘The Yung & Moore Show’).  
album(‘Jessie Evans’, ‘Autonervous’).  
album(‘Bettina Koster’, ‘Autonervous’).  
album(‘Lucia Pamela’, ‘Walkin on the moon’).  
album(‘Shooby Taylor’, ‘The Human Horn’).  
album(‘Tiny Tim’, ‘God Bless Tiny Tim’).  
album(‘The Legendary Stardust Cowboy’, ‘Rock-It to Stardom’).  
vinil(‘Rock-It to Stardom’).  
vinil(‘Walking on the Moon’).  
cd( ‘God Bless Tiny Tim’).  
cd(‘Walking on the Moon’).  
cd(‘Autonervous’).  
cd(‘Manuscription’).  
cassette(‘The Human Horn’).  
cassette(‘The Yung & Moore Show’).  
mp3(‘Walkin on the Moon’).
```

I need to make a query that will return to me all the albums that were made by only one musician.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You probably need `findall/3`. Give it a shot and show us what you come up with.

Comment: Honestly, I have tried lots of things. As I said I'm a beginner I just started learning prolog last week so I don't know much. I don't know how to use the `findall/3` command yet, sorry =/.
I Have tried things like `album(X,B),album(Y,C), B \= C.` But obviously that didnt work xD.

Comment: You can use Google to find information about `findall/3`, for example: https://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_12.html. Also, you have to just think logically through the problem. `album(X,B), album(Y,C), B\=C.` says, *An album called B made by X and an album C made by Y where B and C are different* doesn't describe the query you said you want. Think about what you're wanting in your query. You can ask: *return an album made by musician X* (translate into Prolog) and use `findall/3` to get all of them. Then check if the list obtained has length of `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you have provided your code `album(X,B),album(Y,C), B \= C.` Actually, this is not too far away from a correct solution.

A correct solution could be:

```
one_musician_album(X) :-
    album(A, X), 
    \+ (album(B, X), A \= B).
```

The meaning of the predicate is: an album X is a "one-musician album" if this album is authored by some musician A and it's not possible to find a different musician B authored the album X.

Test run:

```
?- one_musician_album(X).
X = 'Walkin on the moon' ;
X = 'The Human Horn' ;
X = 'God Bless Tiny Tim' ;
X = 'Rock-It to Stardom'.
```

To get all answers you have to type ';' after each answer.

Maybe this is not needed for you, but it's possible to get all answers in a list with `findall`:

```
?- findall(X, one_musician_album(X), Albums).
Albums = ['Walkin on the moon', 'The Human Horn', 'God Bless Tiny Tim', 'Rock-It to Stardom'].
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generalization, based on 'all solutions' builtin [bagof](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3)/3.

Note that

```
?- bagof(A, album(A,T), As).
T = 'Autonervous',
As = ['Jessie Evans', 'Bettina Koster'] ;
T = 'God Bless Tiny Tim',
As = ['Tiny Tim'] 
....
```

then, restricting the authors (As) to be a list of a single element, we get albums with a single author

```
?- bagof(A, album(A,T), [A]).
A = 'Tiny Tim',
T = 'God Bless Tiny Tim' ;
...
```

then, we could use findall/3, as in the good answer by Sergey, or, again, bagof/3, with explicit quantification:

```
?- bagof(T, A^bagof(A, album(A, T), [A]), Ts).
Ts = ['God Bless Tiny Tim', 'Rock-It to Stardom', 'The Human Horn', 'Walkin on the moon'].
```